How to derive the username from the original remote name given on the command line with SSH?
I have 3 machines :

remote.example.org target I'm trying to connect to
bastion.example.org, that is the only "gateway" to this machine, but that can't be used as a proxy as in SSH proxyjump
jump.example.org that I need to access bastion.example.org

Because the bastion uses the username as a way to bring you to the remote server. I can't use it as a regular proxyjump server. For now, if I want to connect to the remote target from the jump server I have to type the following :
ssh -l daftaupe@remote.example.org:daftaupe bastion.example.org

Now I have a working command line from my workstation, that's better than nothing:
ssh -l daftaupe@remote.example.org:daftaupe -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p jump.example.org" bastion.example.org

I would like to put this in my .ssh/config. It is no problem with a single server, and the following snippet allows me to only type ssh remote.example.org.
Host bastion.example.org
    ProxyJump jump.example.org

Host remote.example.org
    Hostname bastion.example.org    
    User daftaupe:remote.example.org@daftaupe

My issue is that I have a few hundreds and they're a moving target, so it's not easy to keep a list of them.
I tried using the following, but there's no way to use %n in the User directive it seems.
Host bastion.example.org
    ProxyJump jump.example.org
    
Host remote.example.org
    Hostname bastion.example.org
    User daftaupe:%n@daftaupe #???

I'm looking for a way so that the User variable would not be static. But I don't see how to derive the username from the original remote name given on the command line, using for example the TOKEN %n in the ssh_config man page, which seems appropriate for my usecase.
I've started writing a little shell wrapper around ssh, but I would prefer to keep everything in the SSH configuration.

The most elegant solution would be to make User support %n. I gave thought to the problem and I think that while some tokens cannot be used in some directives (e.g. because the value of the token is yet to be determined, or some setups could lead to circular references), %n is safe because it's "the original remote hostname, as given on the command line", i.e. already known at runtime, fixed. For any directive that supports any token, there is no reason to exclude %n; still there are directives that don't support %n, as if developers wanted to arbitrarily protect(?) users. (cont'd)

(cont'd) For User there is no token parsing at all, so it's rather a matter of "nobody has requested support for any token here" than "we decided specifically not to support %n here". Consider reaching the developers and ask for the support of %n inside User.

@KamilMaciorowski thanks for the comment, I will try to contact the devs. Are you one of them by the way ?

I am not one of them.

I wanted to do something very similar in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/788360/ssh-including-hostname-in-username , as @KamilMaciorowski pointed out. Have you had a chance to report this in https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/ yet?

A report about other tokens in User: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3477 .

@Richlv I didn't report anywhere yet. Is mindrot.org the official bug reporting tool for OpenSSH ?

The last link I posted seems to be an existing report to support tokens in "User".
